# WPF MVVM DataGrid ComboboxColumn binding to List in my Model

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I am currently working a a WPF project with MVVM.

I have a `DataGrid` bound to an `ObservableCollection` of Models like this:

```
 class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private string m_Name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return m_Name;
        }
        set
        {
            m_Name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    private List<string> m_Names;
    public List<string> Names
    {
        get
        {
            return m_Names;
        }
        set
        {
            m_Names = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Names");
        }
    }

    private double? m_Value;
    public double? Value
    {
        get
        {
            return m_Value;
        }
        set
        {
            m_Value = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Value");
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Now I'd like to use a `DataGridComboBoxColumn` to have a Combobox with my Property "Name" as the SelectedItem and Names as the ItemSource.

Each of my Models has it's own set of names, which aren't identical with the name of any of the other models.

I've googeled and looked through StackOverflow, but I didn't find any solution. I've also tried to aplly filters like i know DevExpress Grid Controls can do, but I didn't find anything for basic WPF DataGrids.

**How can I bind my `DataGridComboBoxColumn` to a Property `List` in my Model?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use DataGridComboBoxColumn you have to feed ItemsSource with a static resource, this is stated in the "Remarks" section 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagridcomboboxcolumn?view=netframework-4.8

Because you have different "Names" for each view model you can use DataGridTemplateColumn instead of DataGridComboBoxColumn

```
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Names}">
                            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ComboBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

What did you try? Provided that the `DataGrid`'s `ItemsSource` property is set or bound to an `IEnumerable<Model>`, this should work:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource="{Binding Names}" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Name}" />
```

Please refer to [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19493.wpf-best-combobox-tutorial-ever.aspx) TechNet article for more suggestions.